# MS Access, VBA - Export Crosstable to Excel

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

**OBJECTIVE**

1. Create crosstable from existing table
2. Export formatted crosstable into excel via VBA

**APPROACH**

1. Created query that pulled necessary data for table
2. Created a crosstable query to properly format data in existing table
3. !HELP NEEDED! Push crosstable query to excel

**ISSUES**

1. I've looked around online and it appears that export a crosstable to excel is difficult - it appears that most forums recommend iterating line-by-line to export the crosstable (this is very surprising). Is there any way I can leverage a method (e.g `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet`) to export a crosstable?

*Why this is so difficult amazes me, apologies for the naivety*

Comment: Do some research on how to create a Pivot query, save it and then youcan export it using transferspreadsheet. if you want to use vba, you could further modified it excel via vba once exported...

Comment: What did you try? What errors do you receive or undesired results? What does data look like for us to reproduce issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up from my original post.
It appears that you *can* use `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` to export a crosstable.

I've defined the working code below:

```
outputQuery = [your cross table query]
outputPath = [save-to file location]
outputFileName = [save-to file name]

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, SpreadsheetType:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, TableName:=outputQuery, FileName:=outputPath & outputfilename
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply create the query I want in MS Access.

Then in excel i have a macro I have written that runs the query and outputs to sheet. see below for an example.

```
Dim cnString As String
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

'Change connection string to an MS Access one
cnString = "Provider=xx;Server=xx,49168;Database=xx;"
rs.Open queryName, cnString, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

'Output Headings
For i = 1 To rs.Fields.Count
        Sheets(PasteSheet).Range(pasteCell).Offset(0, i - 1) = rs.Fields(i - 1).Name
Next i

'Output data
Sheets(PasteSheet).Range(pasteCell).Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset rs
rs.close
```

If you wanted to do all of this in MS Access then it wouldn't take much to modify. You would simply just need to create a new workbook and then do a very similar thing to the above code.